# Finding the Cartesian equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

The task was to make use of the modulus of $|z|=2$ and the argument $\arg(z) = -3\pi/5$
in the form $a+ib$, but to provide the answer in exact form.

I know that I am required to make use of the polar form, $2(\cos(-3\pi/5)+i\sin(-3\pi/5))$, but how do I find the values of both $\cos(-3\pi/5)$ and $\sin(-3\pi/5)$ in exact form.

I think I need to make use of the double angle formula but I am unsure as to how should I apply it here.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\theta = \frac{\pi}{10}$. It follows that $5\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Hence, from $\cos(\alpha) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right)$, we have

$$\cos(3\theta) = \sin(5\theta - 3\theta) = \sin(2\theta)$$

Recall that

$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \tag{1}$$
$$\cos(3\theta) = 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta) \tag{2}$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get

\begin{align}
2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) &= 4\cos^3(\theta) - 3\cos(\theta)\\
\implies \cos(\theta)\left(2\sin(\theta) - 4\cos^2(\theta) + 3\right) &=0\\
\implies 2\sin(\theta) - 4\left(1 - \sin^2(\theta)\right) + 3 &=0\\
\implies4\sin^2(\theta) + 2\sin(\theta) - 1 &= 0\\
\implies \sin(\theta) &= \frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}
\end{align}

Now, using $\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\theta)$, we get

$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) = 1 - 2\left(\frac{-1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{4}$$

Note that $$\cos\left(\frac{-3\pi}{5}\right) = \cos\left(3 \times \frac{\pi}{5}\right) = 4\cos^3\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) - 3\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}$$

Therefore,

$$\sin\left(\frac{-3\pi}{5}\right) = -\sqrt{1 - \cos^2\left(\frac{-3\pi}{5}\right)} = -\sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right)^2} = -\sqrt{\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{8}}$$

Thus,

$$z = 2\left(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{4}\right) + 2i\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}\right) = \boxed{\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} + i\left(-\sqrt{\frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}}\right)}$$